# Creating a 2D grid for a board game in Java using Slick2D

Tags: java, image, grid, rendering, slick2d

I need to create a 2D grid of a fixed size e.g 20x20 using Java slick lib. Currently I have a array [ ][ ] containing symbols (Text). These symbols stand for different tiles (squares) on the board.

I know how to render/draw individual images onto the screen but not sure how to do the same for a grid (loop? wouldn't it be too much rendering for the game?). Should I look into the concept of spritesheets ?

Ideally I thought of creating

1. Tile object: tileXpos, tileYpos, size, image(based on type)
2. Grid object: Tile tiles[ ][ ]

I wouldn't know how to draw/render it to the screen. Also should I initially draw it in the **init** method below and as the game start re-draw accordingly in the **update** method ?

Would appreciate your guidance.

```
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;


public class GameplayState extends BasicGameState {

    public GameplayState(int stateId){

    }


    public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game)
            throws SlickException {
    }

    public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g)
            throws SlickException {
    }

    public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta)
            throws SlickException {
    }

    public int getID() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use TileD: http://www.mapeditor.org/

Slick2D has support to Tiled's .tmx files. Create a 20 x 20 tile map with the symbols. You can access every tile in the tile map and its properties (position, layer, and other custom properties defined in Tiled). And, the best is that you don't have to render the whole map. You can render just a section of it, as you wanted. Take a look here, in Slick2D wiki:

http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=TileD_Import_and_Usage

You can also check it in the javadoc: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/

Say if you need help with the code. n.n